# How can I print reported bugs to console in gradle findbugs plugin?

Tags: plugins, gradle, findbugs

I am using Gradle FindBugs Plugin. How can I print reported bugs to console? PMD plugin has a consoleOutput property. Is there a similar property for FindBugs?

Comment: is your question answered?

Comment: So, you suggest that parse the report and print it, am I right?

Comment: It seems that this is the only workaround for now. See my updated answer.

Comment: My only purpose to print is to make easy to go line, which is reported by findbugs. I may use the ide plugin, which works perfect for this purpose but it is needed to be done this way unfortunately. I think I may sync the includefilter files of both ide and project config file.

Comment: It seems that an IDE plugin will suit your needs perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.FindBugs.html) there's no such property or configuration possibility for FindBugs plugin. However it seems that the plugin can be customized in some way. E.g. by parsing and displaying the results.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263409/maven-findbugscheck-output-summary-of-bugs) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28069712/how-to-write-a-customized-gradle-task-to-not-to-ignore-findbugs-violations-but-f/28098325#28098325).

Answer (score 1):

This is rudimentary ... but it's a start

```
task checkFindBugsReport << {
    def xmlReport = findbugsMain.reports.xml
    if (!xmlReport.destination.exists()) return;
    def slurped = new XmlSlurper().parse(xmlReport.destination)
    def report = ""
    slurped['BugInstance'].eachWithIndex { bug, index ->
        report += "${index + 1}. Found bug risk ${bug.@'type'} of category ${bug.@'category'} "
        report += "in the following places"
        bug['SourceLine'].each { place ->
            report += "\n       ${place.@'classname'} at lines ${place.@'start'}:${place.@'end'}"
        }
    }
    if (report.length() > 1) {
        logger.error "[FINDBUGS]\n ${report}"
    }
}

findbugsMain.finalizedBy checkFindBugsReport
```

Comment: can you share plugin dependencies also

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with [Violations Gradle Plugin](https://github.com/tomasbjerre/violations-gradle-plugin). It is configured with patterns to identify report files and to run after `check`. It will

- Accumulate all static code analysis tools into a unified report.
- Print it to the build log.
- Optionally fail the build if there are too many violations.

Answer (score 0):

Findbugs/Spotbugs come with a class that can run after analysis, read an xml report and print to text/html. It is included in the findbugs/spotbugs.jar file.

```
    <java classname="edu.umd.cs.findbugs.PrintingBugReporter" fork="true">
        <arg value="${build.dir}/findbugs/findbugs-test-report.xml"/>
        <classpath path="${spotbugs.home}/lib/spotbugs.jar"/>
    </java>
```

Which is same as running

```
java  -cp path/to/spotbugs.jar edu.umd.cs.findbugs.PrintingBugReporter  path/to/findbugs-report.xml
```

It has an `-html` option that will render html.

It should be feasible to achieve the same in gradle/maven.